# How to declare the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, credentials, google-speech-api

I am trying the [QuickStart project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api/QuickStart) of the .NET Google Cloud Speech API Samples on my PC (Windows with Visual Studio 2017) but I can't figure where I have to define the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` that must contains the path to the `JSON` account key file.

When I run the project in Visual Studio 2017 it fails on this exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.'`

I have tried to define the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable in the system properties (under *User variables* and *System variables*) like that:

```
C:\GCP_ApiKey\MyFirstProject-599bf9a10431.json
```

But it doesn't work.

Where have I to define `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, I just had to restart the PC for the environment variable to be taken into account…